# Capo di casa vs. capo della casa

Tags: gender

There is a [TV show](https://www.foodnetwork.com/shows/ciao-house) currently in USA that has two hosts, an Italian, and an American of Italian ancestry who (apparently) can speak Italian.  Every episode at least once includes the phrase "capo di casa."  Is that an error or a legitimate Italian expression?  Why is it not "capo della casa"?

Comment: Who/what are they referring to as _capo di/della casa_?

Comment: These American chefs are competing to become the “capo di casa”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Capo di casa' and 'capo della casa' express the same concept. They only interposed a simple preposition (capo **di** casa) and an articulated one (capo **della** casa).
it is therefore not an error and can be considered a legitimate sentence.

Comment: So "di" is not a contraction of "de i"?

Comment: @WGroleau: No, and that's a quite bizarre conjecture, since _de_ is not a word of modern Italian, and _i_ wouldn't agree with _casa_.

Answer (score 2):

"Capo di casa" is indeed correct, bit it's not something we say in Italy. Over here there are two set phrases: "padrone di casa" which means "master of the house" (un buon padrone di casa = a good master of the house, a good host) and the legal term "capofamiglia", head of the family, the person (man or woman) who is the legal head of a family.

Comment: The context is that the the winner of the cooking competition will be "capo di casa."  Does that change your answer?

Comment: @WGroleau: I agree with the answerer that, while _capo di casa_ is a sequence utterable in Italian, it's not quite idiomatic and, if anything, a bit puzzling. In which sense _capo_ (i.e. “chief”)? Do you give orders to other people? Relatives, servants? I'd wonder.

Comment: "Chef" is pretty much French for "chief," and he/she would presumably give orders to others in the kitchen.  Is it idiomatic in that context?  Alex Guarnaschelli is American, but Gabe Bertaccini was born and raised in Firenze.  (But he has been living in Los Angeles for years.)

Comment: Yes, @WGroleau, French _chef_ and English _chief_ are cognate words, and so is, from farther away, Italian _capo_ (all of them descending from Latin _caput_, “head”), but _capo_ has nothing to do with cooks and kitchens. One can be a _capo_ of several things: a military unit, an office, a building site, a caravan, even a team of waiters (and much more), but it's not normally used for a kitchen. Perhaps that phrase was born as an in-joke or as a error someone made.

Comment: Perhaps.  That's basically my question, although it was the 'i' in 'di' that made me incorrectly think masculine plural.

Answer (score 1):

Tbh I've never heard anyone one using that expression. People usually say "Lui è il capo famiglia"